# valums fileuploader doesnt work under IE 9 using spring

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

i am working on file uploading using spring MVC,it work fine in firefox and chrome but in IE its show fail of uploading.. below is my jsp page where i include fileuploader function.

```
<div id="file-uploader-demo1" style="float: left;padding-top: 10px"></div>      

</div>

 <script>        
    function createUploader(){            
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader ({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: '/Flas_ _/commu-____/insertFile;jsessionid=${sessionId}',
            headers: {'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'},
            multipleFileUpload: false,
            debug: true
        });           
    }
    window.onload = createUploader;     
</script>
```

here is my  jsp page where iam including FileUploader.js file  the action tag calls my respective controller which is shown below..

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/insertFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("qqfile") String filename1,ModelMap map, 
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {



    PrintWriter writer = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

      try {
            writer = response.getWriter();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
      String filename =  request.getHeader("X-File-Name");
      this.setFILEUPLOAD(filename);
      try {
            is = request.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/images/" + filename));
            IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
            response.setStatus(response.SC_OK);
            writer.print("{success: true}");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            writer.print("{success: false}");
          //  log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            writer.print("{success: false}");
           // log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }  finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
      writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    return "do-nothing";
}
```

though in CHROME and FIREFOX its works fine and i get the file to store in locale drive. But it doesn't work in IE 9.  what should i do i am not getting.

any solution for dis? plz help Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the other problem (working in IE, not working in FF) by implementing two controller methods. I did not sent explizit headers with the JavaScript uploaders configuration.

One method (for IE) has additional RequestMapping-Options: 
`headers = { "content-type=multipart/form-data" }`

The RequestParam for IE is a `MultipartFile`. From that you will get the filename and the content. The request body of the normal multipart upload used by IE does not only contain the file content as the ajax upload with Firefox does. It also has multipart informationn like the filename and boundaries. `MultipartFile` can handle this for you.

As far as I know, some general settings have to be done to enable your webapp dealing multipart file uploads. But that's another question.